# JavaScript regex returns -1 when > 0 is expected

Tags: javascript, regex

Okay so i have the following string:

```
Aktiv landbruger / Regler AL
```

With this string i attempt to run the following regex:

```
/Regler AL/i
```

However once i run `string.search('/Regler AL/i')`

it returns -1

However when i attempt this on

https://regex101.com/

it returns `0` as it should.

So why is my javascript returning `-1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the regex

```
"Aktiv landbruger / Regler AL".search(/Regler AL/i)
```